# Find sum $S = {n \choose 1} - 2 {n \choose 2} + 3{n \choose 3} - 4{n \choose 4} + \cdots + (-1)^{n} n {n \choose n}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

> Find sum $S = {n \choose 1} - 2 {n \choose 2} + 3{n \choose 3}  - 4{n \choose 4} + \cdots + (-1)^{n} n {n \choose n}$

I need verification of my results.

Assume that $n > 0$
So we see that $k {n \choose k} > 0$ for every odd $k$ , and  $k {n \choose k} < 0$ for every even $k$.

However last term is defined as $(-1)^n n {n \choose n}$, which breaks the pattern, since it's $>0$ for even $n$, and $<0$ for odd $n$.

So I decided to define $S$ as follows:
$S = S + (-1)^{n-1} n {n \choose n} - (-1)^{n-1} n {n \choose n}$.
Obviously, $-(-1)^{n-1} n {n \choose n} = (-1)^n n {n \choose n}$.
So now $S$ looks like this:

$S = {n \choose 1} - 2 {n \choose 2} + 3{n \choose 3}  - 4{n \choose 4} + \cdots + (-1)^{n-1} n {n \choose n} + (-1)^{n} 2n {n \choose n} = (-1)^{n} 2n {n \choose n} + \sum_{k = 1}^{n}(-1)^{k-1} k{n \choose k}$

By [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4397265/1099620) results, we have:

> $\sum_{k = 1}^{n}(-1)^{k-1} k{n \choose k} =\sum_{k = 1}^{n} (-1)^{k-1}n {n-1 \choose k-1} = n\sum_{k = 1}^{n} (-1)^{k-1} {n-1 \choose k-1}= n\sum_{k = 0}^{n-1} (-1)^{k}{n-1 \choose k}=$
> $n\sum_{k = 0}^{n-1} (-1)^{k}1^{n-1-k
> }{n-1 \choose k} = n(1-1)^{n-1} = 0$

Hence, $S = (-1)^{n} 2n {n \choose n}$.

Am I right?  Did I overlook something? Posting this question since my mate somehow found this sum equal to $0$ for every $n$.

UPD.
Indeed, there was a typo. Not mine, but by problem setter. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Looks good. I'll assume your friend didn't see that the last term broke the pattern, since otherwise it would indeed be $0$.

Comment: As you've stated it you are right. But I think there's probably a typo and the last term was meant to be $(-1)^{n+1} n { n \choose n}$.

Comment: If all that we know is that the last term breaks the pattern, then how do we know at which point the pattern is broken? IE How are you so certain that the second last term is $ (-1)^n (n-1) { n \choose n-1}$?  $\quad$ Instead, I think that the more likely explanation is that there was a typo (either by you or the problem setter).

Comment: @CalvinLin you are right. Problem setter made a typo. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $n>1$ we have
$$\sum_{k=0}^nC^k_ns^k=(1+s)^n\Rightarrow \sum_{k=1}^nkC^k_ns^{k-1}=n(1+s)^{n-1}\Rightarrow_{s={-1}} S=0$$